# Jedi VCS is not syncing one file

Tags: delphi, jedi

After losing hours for finding why on my machine the same code was beahving differently i realized that i had a non up to date file locally. Even if the JEDI Sync query returned "all files up to date".

How is this possible? I didn't set any particular flag on this file (at least i didn't to it consciously).

Do you have any idea? Is this maybe a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your computer's clock isn't in the same time of the server, or your file's date/time is incorret.
There are two kind of comparison when synchronizing a project:

- Newer Files
- Different Files

  - by CRC32
  - by ReadOnly Flag

Try to choose "Different Files" and check the "by CRC32" option. It should work.

Comment: Somehow there has nbeen a problem revision N-1 of a file was more recent (as datetime) than revision N. Someone has may be played with server's clock on that day? Anyway now I rechekexced in N-1 and I had all working fine. THe problem is that jedi syncs most recent file and not most recent revisions. It is dangerous.